# How to a convert a string in this format "20180101" into a date value like 01/01/2018 in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What formula can I use to transform the string into a date value that will appear as 01/01/2018?

Answer (score 4):

*If* you are trying to do this from a formula into another cell, and not in situ (For which, use "Text to Columns" as per Jeeped's answer), you can either combine `DATE` and `MID`, or use `REPLACE` and convert with `+0` or `DATEVALUE`:

```
=DATE(MID(A1,1,4), MID(A1,5,2), MID(A1,7,2))
```

OR

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,7,0,"-"),5,0,"-")+0
```

OR

```
=DATEVALUE(REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,7,0,"-"),5,0,"-"))
```

(Where `A1` is the date to convert)

The first formula just cuts the number up into `2018` `01` `01` and uses those as Year, Month and Day.  The second 2 work by first Inserting (i.e. `REPLACE` 0 characters) a hyphen at position 7 (`"201801-01"`) and then at position 5 (`"2018-01-01"`) and converting the string back to a number/date.

Comment: You are a star! the first example solved my issue :)

Comment: You can use T2C either in-place or output to an alternate column. All you have to do is specify the Destination: (located on the same screen as I captured in my response below).

Answer (score 2):

Use Data, TextToColumns, Fixed width, Date: YMD, Finish. Possibly Date: YDM depending on your string date format (you provided an ambiguous example).

[image]

Comment: I have done this and all it does it divide my string into 3 different columns under this format: Column1: 2018 ; Column 2: 1 / Column 3: 1. It didn't transform it into a date value.

Comment: You need to remove the extra fields on the second dialog screen. I didn't mention this because mine didn't show ten when I tested. Just double-click the vertical lines splitting the date or drag them away.

Comment: ... or even use Delimited instead and turn off all delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

use the code below

```
=RIGHT((text),2)&"/"&MID((text),5,2)&"/"&LEFT((text),4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the DATEVALUE() function which takes as input a text format. Not that if your output cell is not in Date format you will see a simple int insteade of the expected 1/1/2016.

I refer you to the DATEVALUE function documentation for more insight on the input format and so on

Comment: This gave me `#VALUE`

Comment: This is because your original cell (the one of the text to input) is not in the 'text' format

Comment: I tried using datevalue before but for =Datevalue("20180101") I get #Value! which kinda makes sense.

Comment: I have changed my column from general to Text - I get the same issue

Comment: I tried formatting as *text* and also using `'20180101` (with apostrophe to force the string) and neither worked

Comment: Indeed the input should be =Datevalue("2018/01/01") you can get that from manipulating your original string and appending some "/"

For example you can do Datevalue(REPLACE(REPLACE("20180101",5,0,"/"),8,0,"/"))